# Accessing function in other kivy sceens

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to figure out how to ensure my the calculations function is available as a global function able to be used no matter where in the app it is called.
Currently I am getting:
AttributeError: 'InputScreen' object has no attribute 'calculations'

main.py

```
import math
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from decimal import Decimal, ROUND_UP
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput

class ScreenSwitch(ScreenManager):
    pass

class DisplayScreen(Screen):
    pass

class InputScreen(Screen):
    pass

class Calculations():
    def calculations(self):
        org_amount = self.ids.orgamount.text
        org_1 = int(self.ids.orgtip.text)
        total = org_amount * org_1

class testApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.title= "test1      v:1"

testApp().run()
```

test.kv

```
ScreenSwitch:
    DisplayScreen:
    InputScreen:



<DisplayScreen>:
    name: "display"
    GridLayout:
        rows:1
        cols:1
        Button:
            id: Displaymanualentry
            text: "Manual Entry"
            on_release: app.root.current = "input"

<InputScreen>:
    name: "input"
    GridLayout:
        rows: 1
        cols: 2
        Button:
            id: Inputreset
            text: "Reset"
            on_release: app.root.current= "display"
        Button:
            id: Inputsubmit
            text: "Submit"
            on_press: root.calculations()
            on_release: app.root.current  = "display"
```

Comment: Your Calculations class isn't being instantiated anywhere. Also, what are you expecting it's `self.ids` to be since it's not a Screen?

Comment: Not sure what instantiated means. I use it on a button, but I am learning so I am trying to figure out how to be able to use the calculation in different places. self.ids is a text input box for user input. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: For example, in code, you're required to have a variable that initializes a `Calculations` class in order to use its methods. Kivy will only create your Screen and App subclasses, not any others, therefore you cannot call the Calculation class functions unless you put an instance of that class inside the others... However, no classes are required to call methods, so it's unclear why you need it. Also, you should be able to set button events in code, not in the KV file